# NSTimeInterval in UTC?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, utc, gmt, nstimeinterval

I am calculating current time Interval using following codes:

```
NSTimeInterval tInt=[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
int tInterval=(int)tInt;
```

Is this timestamp is in utc time ?

I need NSTimeInterval in UTC Time.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is an interval of time, like 5 seconds, 2 hours, 3 days and so on it is not "in timezone" time, it is relative time between two time points.

I'm not sure what exactly you looking for but have a look at [Apple's doc for using timezones](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-BBCBDGID).

Comment: I have to use timestamp (converted to utc time) for some database purpose.